# UITapGestureRecognizer is not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my `storyboard` I have a basic view, with a login field. In the storyboard the checkbox for `Enable user interaction` is checked, and I am also settings this through the code.

Below is the code I'm using for this:

```
class LoginViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        let closeKeyboardGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard");
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(closeKeyboardGesture);

    }

    private func dismissKeyboard() {
        print("Called")
        if passwordField.selected {
            passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        if emailField.selected {
            emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see it's fairly straightforward, however the dismissKeyboard function is never called. What bothers me is I'm using these gestures elsewhere in my application and they're working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That´s because you have your `dismissKeyboard` function marked as `private`. If you are calling a method from a selector and it is private they cannot be called because the method is called from outside.

So remove `private` from `dismissKeyboard` and it will work.

**Update**
If you change the above it will work, what´s not working for you right now is the `resignFirstResponder` You don´t need to the if-checks since you always want to hide the keyboard when you active the `closeKeyboardGesture`, so it´s enough to only call `self.view.endEditing(true)`. I have created a sample project for you that has a working example. You can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq365yukjm4v8e6/TapGestureTest.zip?dl=0).

Comment: @Hobbyist, check the update. You have issues with your keyboard hiding now. I have explained why and also added a sample project to show you how you can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This will do the trick.